# STR_TO_DATE from CSV column returns Null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains VARCHAR in (i.e. 2020-01-12) format, that I would like to convert to "January 12th 2020" date format.

How would one go about this?

Comment: You want to lose the year - is that a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `date_format()` to convert this to a date:

```
select date_format('2020-01-12', '%d %M')
```

Although you should be storing the value as a date, the column will be properly converted to a date.  I would advise you to change it, say:

```
alter table t alter column datecol date;
```